# Error when comparing 'int' type to 'numpy.int32' type

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, typeerror

I am trying to create a new column in my pandas dataframe, based on the value of 2 other columns. I first used a column containing longitude to calculate the time in that location:

```
current_weather['Hour'] = np.where(round(current_weather['Longitude']/15,0) < 0,
                               (round(24 + current_weather['Longitude']/15,0).astype(int)), 
                               (round(current_weather['Longitude']/15,0).astype(int)))
```

The values in this column are numpy.int32.

Then I am creating a column marking if it is day or night by comparing the Hours column to Sunrise and Sunset which are unix timestamps as integers.

```
current_weather['Day/Night'] = np.where((current_weather['Hour'] >= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_weather['Sunrise']).hour) & (current_weather['Hour'] <= datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(current_weather['Sunset']).hour),
                                    'Day','Night')
```

This results in the error

```
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I have tried casting different values to different data types, but can't get anything to work. Can anyone tell me how to get these values into the same data type?

Comment: did you try casting as int with astype(int)?

Comment: `&` is almost certainly not what you want.

Comment: I did that in the above code cell where I calculate 'Hours', but that is returning numpy.int32

Comment: One more thing, my code seems to work correctly when I replace the variable Sunrise and Sunset objects with static integers, 7 and 19.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams why do you say & is not what I want?

Answer (score 1):

You are incorrectly using [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp). It doesn't take a series as input.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> import time
>>> timestamp = time.time()
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 22, 20, 10, 56, 241211)
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> series = pd.Series([1,5,7])
>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(series)
...
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
>>>
```

Since you have sunrise and sunset as seconds, create those as [DateTime series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#epoch-timestamps) and compare against your hour series.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> sunset = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series([1349720105, 1349806505, 1349892905,]), unit='s')
>>> sunset
0   2012-10-08 18:15:05
1   2012-10-09 18:15:05
2   2012-10-10 18:15:05
dtype: datetime64[ns]
>>>
```

Now you can extract hour from these timestamps using [dt accessor](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.html).

```
>>> sunset.dt.hour
0    18
1    18
2    18
dtype: int64
>>> hour = pd.Series([6, 12, 20]) # assume hour you have
>>> hour > sunset.dt.hour
0    False
1    False
2     True
dtype: bool
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks @sathyz for the input, I haven't been able to circle back to this project yet, but I will this weekend.